# OkHttp authenticator

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm using `OkHttp3` and `Retrofit2`.
There was a need to substitute a token for all requests.
I wrote a `TokenAuthentificator` class:

```
   public class TokenAuthenticator implements Authenticator {

        @Override
        public Request authenticate(Route route, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
            return response.request().newBuilder()
                    .header(Const.Url.COOKIE, preferenceHelper.getToken())
                    .build();
        }
    }
```

**and init it with Retrofit:**

```
@Inject
public RestApi(PreferenceHelper preferenceHelper) {
    TokenAuthenticator authenticator = new TokenAuthenticator();

    this.preferenceHelper = preferenceHelper;
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .authenticator(authenticator)
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();


    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Const.Url.API)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
    user = retrofit.create(User.class);
}
```

But, the header in the requests is still not substituted.
What could be the problem?

**Request example:**

```
 @Multipart
    @POST("user_set_photo")
    Observable<Response<TechmasResponse>> setPhoto(@Part("PERSONAL_PHOTO\"; filename=\"image.png\" ") RequestBody file);
```

**In activity/fragments, looks like this:**

```
Subscription request = restApi.user.setPhoto(body)
                .compose(RxUtils.applySchedulers())
                .subscribe(this::successAddPhoto, this::handleError);
        unSubscribeOnDestroy(request);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store token in SharedPrererences and load it from Interceptor:

```
public class TokenAppendingHeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private TokenStorage tokenStorage;

    public TokenAppendingHeaderInterceptor(TokenStorage tokenStorage){
        this.tokenStorage = tokenStorage;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        String token = tokenStorage.getToken();
        Request newRequest = request.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                .addHeader("sessionId", token)
                .addHeader("application-type", "REST")
                .build();
        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
    }
}
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 4):

`Authenticator` is used when you request returns 401 and you need to update your token, otherwise use `Interceptor` in order to update your request (hearders, add token).

**Don't use `Interceptor` to update your token**.

So your `TokenAuthenticator` must implements `Interceptor`.